# Why can't Java open the jvm.cfg file?

Tags: java, minecraft

Every time I try to use the command line to run java *anything*, it gives me this error message:

`Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'`

I'm a beginner coder (trying to set up a Minecraft server), and I've already tried several suggestions (i.e. deleting `java.exe` and rerouting path) but nothing's worked.  The commmand I'm currently trying to use is `./start_minecraft`.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: create an empty file at that location?

Comment: Are you sure you have Java **7** JRE installed?

Comment: I believe so... and I can find the jvm.cfg file, it's not that it is missing...

Comment: Post your command, please

Comment: try if you can open the file with notepad

Comment: I opened it in notepad and it seemed right.  The command I'm trying to use is ./start_minecraft, but it shows the error whenever I try to do anything in java.